# Chrome HTML body scrambling the tags and ruing the design

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I having an issue with this webpage using chrome. When I visit the other pages its fine but when I visited my reservation.php page a empty space is inserted in my html in the inspect view yet in source view is fine. Its ruining my design and I have tried many fixes but still wont work. Its ruing my web page design. This issue only occurs in chrome and tried opera, ie and firefox its working perfectly.

**HTML SOURCE VIEW**
[image] 
**WEB PAGE VIEW**
[image]

**CHROME INSPECT**

As you can see here the metas are inserted at the body with an empty space before the meta..
[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /-->
    <title>Vasquez Compound</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost//public/styles/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost//public/styles/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost//public/styles/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/public/scripts/javascripts/jquery-ui/themes/jquery.ui.all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost//public/styles/reserved-units.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost//public/favicon.png" />
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
      <style type="text/css">
        * {
           filter: none;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/javascripts/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost//public/scripts/javascripts/jquery.1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/public/scripts/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/public/scripts/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/public/scripts/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost//public/scripts/javascripts/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <noscript>
        <div id="no-script-browser">
            <h1>
                Opss its seems your browser this likes our site. Activate your Javascript to  view our website.
                <br> You will be redirected to google.com after 10 seconds.
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="no-script-browser-overlay">
            <table> <tr><td></td></tr> </table>
        </div>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://google.com/">
    </noscript>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="topbar">
          <div id="topbar-content">
            <div class="left upper">For tenants click here to <a href="login.php">LOGIN</a><!--OR <a href="">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</a>--> </div>
            <div class="left mleft10"> 
                <a href="contact-us.php">SUPPORT</a> <!--| <a href="">MY UNIT</a!--> | 
                <a href="reservation.php">RESERVED UNITS (<span id="session-reserved-units">1</span>)</a> </div>
            <div class="right">
              <form method="get">
                <input type="text" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Keyword to search" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
          <ul>
            <li id="home"><a href="http://localhost/"><img src="http://localhost//public/styles/images/home.png" width="24" height="26"></a></li>
            <li><a href="units.php">Units</a></li>
            <li><a href="locations.php">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservation.php" class="selected">Reservation</a></li>
            <li><a href="quote.php">Make a Quote</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="banner">
          <div class="left"> 
                    <img src="http://localhost//public/images/banners/reservation.png" width="745" height="250">
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul id="utypes">
              <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Bungalows</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Duplex</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Condominiums</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Apartments</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
        </div>
          </div>
      <div id="contents"> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("input.mau").click(function(e) {
                $("input.mau").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.disabled = true;
                });
                $("input.umau").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.disabled = false;
                });
                $("input.chk").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.checked = true;
                });
            });
            $("input.umau").click(function(e) {
                $("input.mau").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.disabled = false;
                });
                $("input.umau").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.disabled = true;
                });
                $("input.chk").each(function(index, element) {
                    element.checked = false;
                });
            });
            $("input.chk").each(function(index, element) {
                $(element).click(function(e) {
                    $("input.mau").each(function(i, el) {
                        el.disabled = $("input.chk:checked").get().length  == $("input.chk").get().length ? true : false;
                    });
                     $("input.umau").each(function(i, el) {
                        el.disabled = $("input.chk:checked").get().length  > 0 ? false : true;
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="page-contents">
      <div id="reserved-units">
        <form method="post">
        <div class="controls"> 
            <input type="button" value="Check All Units" class="mau" />
            <input type="button" value="Uncheck All Units" class="umau"  disabled />
            <input type="submit" value="Post Reservations" class="right" name="post-reservation"  />
            <input type="submit" value="Remove Selected Units" class="right" name="remove-units"  />
        </div>
            <div class="img-unit"> <img src="http://localhost//public/images/units/d1f92cf44b49d8ecaeda81ded08c8f97.jpg" class="unit-image">
          <div class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk" name="uid[]" />
            <b title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis.Unit 1"> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ame... </b> </div>
        </div>
            <span class="clear"></span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"> 
        <div id="footer-content">
            <div class="left pd10 ftw">
                <h4>HOUSE TYPES</h4>
                <hr />
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Bungalows</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Duplex</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Condominiums</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Apartments</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="left pd10 ftw">
                <h4>Services</h4>
                <hr />
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Make a quote</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Maintainance</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="odd-type">Emergency response</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="" class="even-type">Other Services</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             <div class="right pd10">
                <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                <hr />
                <form method="post" action="contact-us.php" id="frmFooterContactForm">
                <ul class="left">
                  <li><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter full name" required /></li>
                  <li><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter valid email address" required /></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="mno" placeholder="Enter mobile number" required /></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject" required /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="right rbox">
                <textarea placeholder="Enter your message" name="content" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="smsg" id="smsg" value="Send Message" required class="clear" />
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="clear align-center" id="end">  
                &copy; UVCCS Students &trade; All Rights Reserved 2013-2014        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry Im just new to this...

Comment: Can you show us your code inline, instead of in a screenshot?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel heres a link of the files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0kuzjowaxhrm0cu/lmodTCRDa1/chrome-issue

Comment: No, I meant the rendered HTML and please paste it into your question, if your Dropbox code is gone this question gets useless.

Comment: Please format your code as well.

Comment: Make sure your document is valid:  http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I already validated it and the only problem is this one page the others are really working just fine and without empty space and html scambling..

Comment: Just a comment unrelated to your question, but your noscript message "Opss its seems your browser this likes our site." makes no sense! Perhaps "Ooops, this site needs javaScript enabled to function correctly" would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an error in your HTML somewhere, because in the Chrome inspector the `<meta>` and `<link>` tags are placed in the `<body>`, not in the `<head>`.

Comment: You can check my code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0kuzjowaxhrm0cu/lmodTCRDa1/chrome-issue

I reviewed my code and it seems no error to me...

Comment: When I copy and paste your HTML code in my local setup, my Chrome (25.0.1364.160) inspector shows no empty block and the HTML is correct as well and not scrambled. I'm sorry, but it seems I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: PS. I'm also not seeing the 'style="display:block;"' in the body tag locally. Your javascript files are not loaded in my setup (because of the local paths). Are you sure that one of those files isn't the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I found a solution.. it seems there are some unknown characters that cant be seen.. I dont know how did it get there but i tried to copy the codes and paste in notepad++ then copy it the codes from notepad++ then replaced the php file.. it worked out...

Thanks for all your help and suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, all my code was W3C compliant and in the Chrome inspector all the head content was in the body tag. After research, I discovered that Chrome Inspector bug when the file is encoded with UTF-8 WITH BOM.

To resolve the problem, encode your file with **UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM**.